# How can I create a scatterplot with multiple expressions on y axis and time on x axis?

Tags: python, excel, matplotlib

I am analyzing advertisements from magazines and want to prove that the core message of the advertisements shifted during the last 40 years. The 4 core messages are: functionality, reliability, convenience and price. Since I have a lot of magazines to got through the fastest way is to note year and month of the magazine and then make a cross in the specific column. Thus my table looks like this:

| Year-Month-Number | functionality | reliability | convenience | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1950-1-1 | x |  | x |  |
| 1950-1-2 | x |  |  |  |
| 1950-1-3 | x | x |  |  |
| 1950-2-1 |  | x |  |  |
| 1950-2-1 | x | x | x | x |

I have approximately 5000 rows and I want to create a scatter plot or dot plot where the x axis shows the time and the y axis the 4 expressions. So for the first row of the table there would be 2 dots in the diagram: one dot for functionality and one for convenience.

In the end it should look like this:[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGCDt.jpg)

I tried to find threads or similar questions which wasn't successful and somehow I struggle with the correct wording for my problem. I have some basic python (jupyter) knowledge, but an excel solution would be alright too.

Thanks in advance. Please be gentle. My first stackoverflow question.

Comment: Use separate charts as overlays ie stacked.

Comment: A few ways to do this, but one option is to give each "message" an index (e.g., functionality=1, price=4); and then replace the "x" with with that index; then you should be able to make a normal scatter plot and simple change your y-axes labels from the indices to the words. Should work in Excel, matplotlib, really any plotting software.

Comment: I can share a solution in Python. What does the Number in Year-Month-Number mean? Is it a magazine number associated with a unique date/week of publication? Or is it the number of an advertisement contained in a monthly magazine? If it is the latter, using Year-Month-Number as a time variable for the x-axis in a plot will make the points of each month overlap.